# Not able to type in DatagridView in windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 3 columns in my datagridview and I set all the columns' read only property true except one and make it read only false.

- So issue is I just can't type any thing in datagrid column from keyboard whereas when I copy some text and paste it in the same column it works fine. I can't figure it out why its happening.

I am not setting any other properties else of it.
Here is my code:

```
         `var dt = new DataTable();
          dt.Columns.Add("Item Code").ReadOnly = true;
          dt.Columns.Add("Qty").ReadOnly = false;
          dt.Columns.Add("Description").ReadOnly = true;
          ExcelDataGridView.DataSource = dt;`
```

Comment: Post your code. What other properties or events are you leveraging?

Comment: paste with mouse or keyboard?

Comment: Is your DataGrivView subscribed to any events?

Comment: Yes, CellClick Event , Selection changed and Cell value changed

Comment: Yes TaW I have paste it from keyboard from another form

Comment: The posted code does not reproduce the problem. I can type into the second column.  Is your ExcelDataGridView.ReadOnly property set to true?